# How to get backports for tomcat?

Tags: apt, software-installation, tomcat, backport

I installed tomcat 7 using apt-get utility on my ubuntu server 13.04. 
So do I need to manually configure, after this to start receiving backports/fixes for tomcat ? If yes, then how do I confgure?

Or ubuntu, by itself, takes care of that ?

Answer (score 1):

What server version are you using?

If it's 12.04 LTS and you are using the Ubuntu packages then you are stuck at 7.0.26. If you want to run newer versions of Tomcat7 on 12.04 then you will need to manually install Tomcat7.

Comment: i m asking for backports not upgrades..btw i'm on 13.04

Answer (score 1):

You can install an additional repository like: https://launchpad.net/~dirk-computer42/+archive/ubuntu/c42-backport

where (as of July'14) you can get: *tomcat 7.0.52*

Probably you want to add the repository by:

```
 sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dirk-computer42/c42-backport
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```